# Many long lasting CLOSE_WAIT connections in Grails application

Tags: grails, nginx, tcp, tomcat7, rest-client

I've got a Grails application deployed on Apache Tomcat 7. Last week the application was down due to empty thread pool but there's not so many users to make this happened. When I looked to server, I found out there's a lot of java threads and tcp processes on port 8080 which are not closed - in state CLOSE_WAIT.

[Screenshot of netstat for 8080 port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3tKjL.png)

The application communicates with a remote MSSQL database and also with remote CRM system through groovy.net.http.RestClient. As a webserver we're using Nginx. I looked into all logs (tomcat, nginx access log) and didn't realize any strange activity. Did anyone face issue like this on similar technologies?

Grails version is 2.3.7

Here's a connection setting to db:

```
production {
    dataSource {
        // Production MS SQL database configuration
        //pooled   = true
        driverClassName = "net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver"
        url = "jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://blahblahblah"
        username = "username"
        password = "password"
        dbCreate = "none"
        properties {
           // See http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#dataSource for documentation
           jmxEnabled = true
           initialSize = 5
           maxActive = 1250
           minIdle = 20
           maxIdle = 100
           maxWait = 15000
           maxAge = 10 * 60000
           timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis = 5000
           minEvictableIdleTimeMillis = 60000
           validationQuery = "SELECT 1"
           validationQueryTimeout = 3
           validationInterval = 15000
           testOnBorrow = true
           testWhileIdle = true
           testOnReturn = false
           jdbcInterceptors = "ConnectionState"
           defaultTransactionIsolation = java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED
        }
    }
  }
```

**UPDATE**

I found out that the CLOSE_WAIT connection arises at the same time as nginx 499 error - client close request.

Comment: What version of Grails? Could you put a mssql connection code. Is it using connection pool?

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Grails 2 project anymore. And i have never seen this error. But I don't usually use jtds driver. This is what i use.

```
driverClassName: "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
dialect: "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect"
url: "jdbc:mysql://localhost/myroject?useUnicode=yes&characterEncoding=UTF-8"
```

I remember in old days i had to download DB driver and add it to lib directory.

Comment: I found out that the CLOSE_WAIT connection arises at the same time as nginx 499 error - client close request.